# What is the spiritual / mystical significance of the Northern vs Southern kingdoms?

Tags: tanach

The events in the Torah are often given spiritual or mystical meanings. For example, Yaakov and Eisav represent the spiritual and physical natures of man.

However when it comes to the Prophets, we don't see as much of this deeper meaning attached. For example, is there a deeper meaning to the Northern vs Southern kingdoms? What do those represent in our lives today?

Comment: I haven't learned it personally yet, but I am looking forward to learning Torah Ohr and Lekutei Torah by the Alter Rebbe, who goes through each parasha and gives us the meaning and avodah in every one of us for the Avot, the 12 Tribes, the Kings. I'm sure that's a good direction to find an answer for this. Hatzlacha rabba

Comment: https://www.jewishusedbooks.com/product.asp?productid=7599